# First In App Purchase - Invalid product id

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

this is the first time I set up an In App Purchase and I am stuck. When I try to make a Product Request I receive the error "Invalid product id: TVRBIBLIA001". I was seeing several questions in Stack Overflow looking for possible solutions without success, so, I post my own. This is the set up of my In App Purchase.

[image: In App Purchase Set Up 1]
[image: In App Purchase Set Up 2]

And this is my code:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Remove Ads InApp Purchase
- (IBAction)requestRemoveAdsProductData
{
    NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:@"TVRBIBLIA001"];
    productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
    productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [productsRequest start];

    // we will release the request object in the delegate callback
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SKProductsRequestDelegate methods

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSArray *products = response.products;
    removeAdsProduct = [products count] == 1 ? [[products firstObject] retain] : nil;
    if (removeAdsProduct)
    {
        NSLog(@"Product title: %@" , removeAdsProduct.localizedTitle);
        NSLog(@"Product description: %@" , removeAdsProduct.localizedDescription);
        NSLog(@"Product price: %@" , removeAdsProduct.price);
        NSLog(@"Product id: %@" , removeAdsProduct.productIdentifier);
    }

    for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
    {
        NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);
    }

    // finally release the reqest we alloc/init’ed in requestProUpgradeProductData
    [productsRequest release];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification object:self userInfo:nil];
}
```

Comment: i was having the same problem when I realized that as long as the language remains pending you won't get valid product from Store. do a simple edit of the langauge you added like adding a '.' and check for products again. You must have submitted your app for inApp purchases to work for details visit http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

Comment: @tGilani Where does the '.' goes? http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/155/screenshot20120813at093.png/

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** Deleted the App from the device and reinstalled id. [Via](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/)